# Convert data frame columns into vectors stored in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, numeric

I have data consisting of many columns/variables and three rows. Each variable is an integer and the values vary across rows and columns. Below is a minimal example of my data:

```
# Minimal example of data frame I have
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3), 
                 x2 = c(4,1,6), 
                 x3 = c(3,0,2), 
                 x4 = c(3,0,1))
```

I am trying to somehow collapse each column into a numeric vector containing the values in each row. For example, I want something like:

```
# Desired data based on minimal example
 target_list <- list(c(1,2,3),
                     c(4,1,6),
                     c(3,0,2),
                     c(3,0,1))
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to take another data frame with many columns and generate a new data frame containing only the columns with indices matching the values in each numeric vector. For each vector, I generate another data frame. All frames are stored in a list. An example of my target output given the working example inputs:

```
# Example "super data frame" I will subset. The values contained in each column are arbitrary.
 df2 <- data.frame(z1 = "a", z2 = "b",
                   z3 = 999, z4 = NA, 
                   z5 = "foo", z6 = "bar")

# Subset "super data frame" to only columns in each vector in the list, store in a list
list(df2[ ,target_list[[1]]],
     df2[ ,target_list[[2]]],
     df2[ ,target_list[[3]]],
     df2[ ,target_list[[4]]])
```

I've tried various pasting approaches, but they produce character vectors that I can't use to select the columns of the other data frame by index, e.g. it produces this:

```
 paste0(df[1, ], df[2, ], df[3, ], df[4, ])
```

Any help on how to generate the list of numeric vectors from df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but the only difference between your input and your target are three attributes:

```
attributes(df)
#$names
#[1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4"
#
#$class
#[1] "data.frame"
#
#$row.names
#[1] 1 2 3
```

You can remove them:

```
attributes(df) <- NULL
df
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 1 6
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 0 2
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 3 0 1
```

Or, alternatively:

```
c(unname(unclass(df)))
```

But, of course, these attributes don't hurt and you can always treat a data.frame like a list (because it actually is a list).

Comment: This actually is incredibly simple and does the job. Does removing the attributes of the data frame produce the desired result because data frames are just lists with certain attributes?  After removing the attributes, str(df) shows I now have a list and the attributes(df) <- NULL is identical to as.list(df).  It's not immediately clear to me why these are equivalent.

Comment: A data.frame is a list. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Or use `as.list`

```
as.list(df)

#$x1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$x2
#[1] 4 1 6

#$x3
#[1] 3 0 2

#$x4
#[1] 3 0 1
```

You can use `unname` to remove names of the list.

Comment: This is also good and I've upvoted, but the other option provides a bit more of the logic for why this works..